# How to pass values from pop up window to parent window through jquery in MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

i have three buttons in my view page says **"Button1"**, **"Button2"** & **"Button3"** and i have three TextBoxes corresponds to each button says **"TextBox1**",**"TextBox2"** & **"TextBox3"** . When clicking on any one button i m able to open one pop up window. Now i want to pass some values to the parent view from POP up view and pass that value to the TextBox associate with the button which is being clicked. How can i do this?

**Edit**

```
<input type="button" value="Buuton1" id="Button1" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px; onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home" ) %>');" /> 
<input type="button" value="Button2" id="Button2" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px;" onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home" ) %>');" /> 
<input type="button" value="Button3" id="Button3" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px;" onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home" ) %>');" />
```

Comment: Hi @Saloni, we need some code to be able to help you.

Comment: <input type="button" value="Buuton1" id="Button1" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px; onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home"  ) %>');" />  <input type="button" value="Button2" id="Button2" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px;" onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home"  ) %>');" />  <input type="button" value="Button3" id="Button3" style="width:100px;font-family:Verdana; font-size:9px;" onclick="window.open( '<%= Url.Action( "Popup", "Home"  ) %>');" />

Comment: I have three texboxes on the view page:  <%= Html.TextBox("TextBox1","" , new { style = "width:40px;font-family:Verdana;font-size:9px;"}%>  ,TextBox2, Textbox3  Now when i click on any of the button i m able to get one popup window name "Popup". In that Popup window i have one button and one textbox. When i put some values on the textbox and after clicking on the button i want to populate the textbox value to the parent window and close the popup window.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give an id to the textboxes (for example `textBox1`), then try this..it's a simple JavaScript.
You don't need jQuery for this.

```
window.opener.document["nameForm"].getElementById("textBox1 ").value = "your some values will go here"
```

Comment: giving error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Unable to get value of the property 'getElementById': object is null or undefined

Comment: have you added id to textbox and then are you passing this id to `'getElementById'` function?

Comment: as you have said me to do window.opener.document["nameForm"].getElementById("textBox1 ").value = "your some values will go here" i have done the same

Comment: i have told i have only three button on the page and three textbox not more than that.

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using jquery OR Javascript. here we are going to discuss with email id updates.

in bellow example a pop up window will open with auto fill email id from parent window.
after update, a email will automatically  update in parent window text box and pop up window will have closed autocratically.

Example:

1) Create **file index.html as** a parent windows

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN”>
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>

<body>
<table>

<tr>
<td colspan=”2″>Example for update email id.</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Email Id:</td>
<td>
<input type=’text’ name=”emailID” id=”emailId” value=”demo@demo.com”></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<input type=”button” name=”update” value=”Update”
onClick=’window.open(“update_popup.html”, “”, “width=400, height=300″)’>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Create **file update_popup.html as a** pop up window where email id auto fill from parent window for update.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC “-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN”>
<html>
<title></title>
<head></head>
<script src=”http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js”></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//== pre fill parent window email id in popup window for update

var emailId = window.opener.document.getElementById(“emailId”).value;
$(“#emailId”).val(emailId);

//=== update updated email id in to parent window

$(“#Save”).on(‘click’,function(){

var updated_emailId = $(“#emailId”).val();
window.opener.document.getElementById(“emailId”).value = updated_emailId;
window.close();
});
});
</script>

<body>
<table>
<tr>
<td>Email Id:</td>
<td>
<input type=’text’ name=”emailID” id=”emailId” value=””></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type=”button” name=”Save” id=”Save” value=”Save”></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

for more click on.

http://www.delhincrjob.com/blog/how-to-get-the-parent-window-element-value-in-popup-window-using-jquery/