# pop up window based on php input value

Tags: php, javascript

I have an `edit_ticket_check.php` page like this:

```
<form name="frm" action="edit_ticket_asso.php" method="post" onSubmit="return validt(frm)">
  <table frame=box align=center bgcolor="9966FF">
    <b><h2>Enter Ticket Information</h2></b> 
  </table>
</form>
```

Then some boxes like this:

```
<tr><td><font color="BLACK">Ticket Status:</font></td>
<td>
<?php 
  echo "<select name=\"ticket_status\">";  
  echo "<option size =15 selected>Select</option>"; 
  if(mysql_num_rows($result4))  
  {  
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result4))  
    {  
      echo "<option>$row[ticket_status]</option>";  
    }  
  }  
  else { 
    echo "<option>No Status Present</option>";   
  }  
?> 
</td>
```

The input values go to a second `edit_ticket.php` page where it enters the value in a MySQL database.

```
if($_POST['submit']=="Insert")
{
  $ticket_no=$_POST['ticket_no'];
  if ( @$_SESSION[username] == 'admin')
  {
    $assigned_to=$_POST['emp_name'];
  }
  else
    $assigned_to = @$_SESSION[userid][0];

  $reassigned_to_team=$_POST['reassigned_to_team'];
  $ticket_status=$_POST['ticket_status'];
  $comment=$_POST['comment'];
  if($ticket_no!=NULL&&$assigned_to!=NULL&&$comment!=NULL)
  {
    $query1=mysql_query("select count(ticket_no) as total from ticket where ticket_no='$ticket_no';");

    $row = mysql_fetch_array($query1);
    if ($row["total"]>"0")
    {
      $query2="UPDATE ticket SET ticket.assigned_to='$assigned_to', ticket.reassigned_to_team='$reassigned_to_team', ticket.ticket_status='$ticket_status', ticket.comment='$comment' WHERE  ticket.ticket_no='$ticket_no'";

      $result1=mysql_query("$query2");
    }
  }
}
```

Now after this I want that if ticket status = 'pending' then a new pop up window will come up and take a time value and then update the time value of ticket by the newly entered time.

For the pop up window I have this code:

```
<html>
<body>

<p>Click the button to add resolution time with pending ticket.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Pending</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script type="text/javascript">
function myFunction()
{
  var x;

  var name=prompt("Please enter Resolution Time","2099-12-31 23:59:59");

  if (name!=null)
  {
    x="resolution_time " + name ;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=x;
  }
}
</script>
```

Now I can't connect these two pages and I'm also unable to pass the values from the new pop up window to old window.

How can i do this?

Since PHP is a server-side language so it can't be dyanamic like JavaScript which is a client-side language, do you have any better idea to do this other way round?

thank you..

Comment: You might want to take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6422958/how-to-pass-values-from-pop-up-window-to-parent-window-through-jquery-in-mvc

Comment: @Patrick now its like some button boxes that always will be there. but mine is a bit different... the pop up window only comes up when the ticket_status=='pending'... otherwise it will be normal php...

Answer (score 0):

Your landing page (the one that your form processor page, edit_ticket.php should redirect to when it's finished) should accept a parameter in the url. Based on that, you can write javascript in the new page to decide whether or not to open the pending window.

For example: at the end of edit_ticket.php,

```
header("location: landing.php?pending=1");
```

and then in pending:

```
<?php 
    if (isset($_GET['pending']) && $_GET['pending'] ==1){
        ?><script type='text/javascript'>
            window.open('yourpopup.html');
        <?php
      }
?>
```