# Opening a Modal Window "using" PHP

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I am creating a log in system in PHP and I'm trying to make it a little nicer.

When you log out, you get redirected back to index.php. Like this:

```
header("loaction: index.php?logout=true")
```

This makes the url look like www.mysite.com/index.php?logout=true. I then use the following code:

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

$logoutvalue = $_GET['logout'];

if($logoutvalue = "true") {
$notification = "You've been logged out!";  
}
```

to get the value of logout from the URL and do something with it.

I have a small popout window that will display the notification variable's value. In this case it's "You've been logged out!" My question is how do I get the modal window to display when the page loads and when the url equals /index.php?logout=true ?

All comments, answers, and suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks!
- Ryan

Comment: header location should use a full URI .

Comment: It's just on localhost, so that will change once it's live.

Comment: you could write a javascript based on the $_GET value.. isnt this similar to this question here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11594974/pop-up-window-based-on-php-input-value

Comment: @BharathParlapalli I don't think it's similar. Mine is a lot more simpler. I just need to open a Modal Window using PHP somehow. There has got to be some way to do it! Haha. And I thought about the JavaScript thing. I honestly just don't know how.. And since I don't know, I don't even know if that would work.

Answer (score 4):

First of all,

You can't "Open a Modal Window using PHP" directly. 
You can only do this only by exchanging variables (via JSON or XML), or embedding PHP conditions right into your markup.

PHP and JavaScript are independent.

> My question is how do I get the modal window to display when the page
>   loads and when the url equals /index.php?logout=true ?

There are two ways you can achieve this. 
**First**: Make a good use of embedding PHP conditions right into the markup.

**Second**: Have somewhere hidden input, like (`<input type="hidden" id="showModal" />`) and then check if it exists via JavaScript itself.

For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

   <script type="text/javascript">

      window.onload = function(){

           if ( document.getElementById('showModal') ){

               alert('Box'); //replace with your own handler
           }

      }

   </script>

</head>
<body>

<?php if ( isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] === 'true' ): ?>

<input type="hidden" id="showModal" />

<?php endif;?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for something like:

```
<script>
<?php if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] === 'true'){
    echo 'alert("You\'ve been logged out!");'
}
?>
</script>
```

EDIT: I believe you are looking for something like this for a modal window (using jQuery)

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] === 'true'){
    $message = "You've been logged out!";
?>
    <script>
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog();//if you want you can have a timeout to hide the window after x seconds
    });
    </script>
    <div id="dialog" title="Basic dialog">
        <p><?php echo $message;?></p>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Not exactly. I don't want a JavaScript alert box. I want to display the modal box. So like if I was to click a link in html then the code would be `<a href="#popout">Open Popout</a>` if that helps any. The modal window looks nicer. :P

Comment: Do you know how to create a modal box that appear/disappear on some JS event?

Comment: Also you'll have to get [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/download) and a UI CSS to have it display.

Comment: @Class Just a question (I have no idea) shouldn't it be `$("#dialog").modal();`. And the Edit didn't work either. I don't know if this would be helpful, but this is where I got my Modal Plugin. http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/login-box-modal-dialog-window-with-css-and-jquery/.

Comment: @RyanFitzgerald I was giving you a jQuery UI example which is `.dialog();` the site you got yours will work the same you just have to modify it accordingly to how you what it to look like.

Answer (score 2):

I know it is an old post, but to help someone in future with similar quest, I guess the following may help to get into right directions ( I have tested the below code myself, so please make adjustment).

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] === 'true'){
        $message = "You've been logged out!";
    ?>
        <script>
        $(function() {
         $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
        </script>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Data</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="fetched-data"><?php $message ?></div> 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php } ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so your existing code is like this snippet, and the problem you're having is that you want to show a jQuery/Bootstrap modal triggered by/with PHP, but jQuery/JS hasn't loaded yet (so you'll get a "$ undefined" error).

When you say "a small popout window" I'm assuming you mean a bootstrap type modal.

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  $logoutvalue = $_GET['logout'];

  if($logoutvalue = "true") {
    $notification = "You've been logged out!";  
  }
}
```

What I did was move the PHP code block to the end of the .php file, after jQuery (etc), and have an include, so it would look like this (assuming the name of your modal is id="logoutModal"):

**logout.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
  $logoutvalue = $_GET['logout'];

  if($logoutvalue = "true") {
    include("logout-modal.php");  
  }
}
```

**logout-modal.php**

```
<?php ?>
  <script>
    $('#logoutModal').modal('show');
  </script>
<?php ?>
```

Not 100% sure this answers your question, but this works for me. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Best way to get done this by using the [PRG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

### index.php

**1. Create the element for modal content in HTML**

```
<div id=modal></div>
```

**2. Style your `#modal` element**

```
#modal {
    position: fixed;
    display: none; /*important*/
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1000;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    background: crimson;
    line-height: 2;
}
```

**3. Define function how to show and disappear the modal box using jQuery**

```
'use strict'

window.jQuery ?

    $.fn.notify = function(interval) {      
        let el = $(this),
            text = el.text(),

            modal =()=> { // this will fire after the interval has expired
                el.fadeOut(),
                clearInterval(timer)
            },

            timer = setInterval(modal,interval)

        !text.match(/\S+/) || el.text('') // this will fire when modal box contains text    
            .append(`<h3>${text}</h3>`)
            .show()
    }

: alert('jQuery required.')
```

**4. Attach `.notify()` to the jQuery selector**

```
$(()=>{
    $('#modal').notify(1500) // 1500 is the interval in milliseconds
})
```

**5. Insert the notification sent from PHP inside the `#modal` element**

```
<div id=modal>
    <?=
        @$_SESSION["notify"]; // if this variable is not set, nothing will happen
        unset($_SESSION["notify"]); 
    ?>
</div>
```

**6. Perform a simple `$_GET` request**

```
<a href=parse.php?logout>Logout</a>
```

### parse.php

**7. Return a value using PHP in a `$_SESSION` variable**

```
if (isset($_GET["logout"])) {
    $_SESSION["notify"] = "You have been logged out.";
    header("Location: index.php");
}
```

This is good practice. Once the logout request is sent to PHP, it will redirect to the index page with the result in a session variable. The PRG pattern does not always require a POST request. This example sends a GET request which is ok for logouts. Note that you have to place `session_start();` at the top of your files.

Answer (score -1):

Or you could even write the script inside if statement:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['logout']) && $_GET['logout'] === 'true'){ ?>
    <script type="text/javascript>
     window.open(yourhtml);
 </script>
</php } 
else {
// may be some other script
}
?>
```

Comment: how is this different from what @Class suggested? just want to know why the negative rating.

Answer (score -1):

Please download a Modal JS Library http://simplemodal.plasm.it

and Use the Condition

```
if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {

$logoutvalue = $_GET['logout'];

if($logoutvalue = "true") {
code to open the Modal as in the JS library..... 
}
```