# How to open a bootstrap modal with PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am creating a wedding website containing a PHP form for RSVPs. I am a novice at best.

What I am trying to do is, once a user fills out and submits the form, the web page either takes them to a success/thank-you page. *(this part is working)*.

Or if the form is not filled out correctly, it shows a bootstrap modal which tells them what they did wrong. *(this is what I am having trouble with)*.

Here is my code that has to do with the modal part.

In my mind, my PHP `if` statement should run the JavaScript when there is any sort of error. And the JavaScript should open a modal window showing the errors. What is not connecting?

```html
<?php
    if ($_POST["submit"]) {
      $result='<div class="alert alert-success">Form submitted</div>';

      if (!$_POST["name"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the name on your invitation.";
      }
      if (!$_POST["head-count"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please enter the size of your party.";
      }
      if (!$_POST["reception-check"]) {
        $error.="<br> Please let us know if you will be attending the reception.";
      }
      if ($error) { ?>
        <script type="text/javascript"> $('#myModal').modal('show'); </script>
        <?php
      } else {
        if (mail("dprb17@gmail.com", "RSVP", "

        Name: ".$_POST['name']."

        Head Count: ".$_POST['head-count']."

        Reception Check: ".$_POST['reception-check']."

        Comments: ".$_POST['comments'])) {
          header("location: http://www.ourpeachwedding.com/pages/thankyou.php");
          exit();
        } else {
          $result='<div class="alert alert-danger"><strong>Sorry, there was an error submitting your rsvp, please try again.</strong>'.$error.'</div>';
        }
      }
    }

    ?>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <?php echo $result ?>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

```html
    <div id="rsvp">
      <div class="jumbotron">

        <?php echo $result; ?>

        <div class="container-fluid">
          <p class="text-center h1">RSVP</p>
          <p class="lead text-center">Even if you are not planning to attend, please RSVP anyway.</p>
          <div class="row">
            <div class=" col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
              <form method="post">
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Name:</span>
                  <input name="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="What was the name on the invitation?" value="<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>">
                </div> <!--/.input-group-->
                <hr>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Head Count:</span>
                  <input name="head-count" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="How many in your party?" value="<?php echo $_POST['head-count']; ?>">
                </div> <!--/.input-group-->
                <hr>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Reception?</span>
                  <input name="reception-check" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Will you be attending the reception?" value="<?php echo $_POST['reception-check']; ?>">
                </div> <!--/.input-group-->
                <hr>
                <div class="input-group">
                  <span class="input-group-addon">Comments:</span>
                  <textarea name="comments" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="eg. gluten/food allergies, not attending, etc."><?php echo $_POST['comments']; ?></textarea>
                </div> <!--/.input-group-->
                <hr>
                <div class="text-center">
                  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-large" value="Submit">
                </div> <!--/.text-center-->
              </form>
            </div> <!--/.col-->
          </div> <!--/.row-->
        </div> <!--/.container-fluid-->
      </div> <!--/.jumbotron-->
    </div> <!--/#rsvp-->
```

Comment: your acceptance record is questionable

Comment: First of all, the modal would be displayed by the javascript on the page in the browser, not directly by the php code. If you want to display the modal, you will need something in the page sent to the browser to cause it to display.

Comment: what does that mean @Fred-ii-

Comment: it means that all your past questions where solutions were given were not accepted. This shows that none are solved.

Comment: So then what would be the best way to go about invoking a modal when a user submit a form with errors? @SloanThrasher

Comment: @Fred-ii- I don't exactly know how to use stackoverlow in great detail, is that something I need to fix? and how?

Comment: You could use the on document ready event to call a function to display the modal.

Comment: @SloanThrasher wouldnt that just display the modal as soon as the page loads up? I only want it to display if the user entered something incorrect in the form.

Comment: You need to implement form validation in JavaScript and not in PHP to utilize modal.

[This][1] example should help you get started. I recommend learning basics of JavaScript as you will need to frequantly if you are developing for web.


  [1]: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_validation.asp

Comment: Running validation on PHP side is like going to the grocery store to look at what is missing in the refrigerator.

Comment: If your wedding is soon, consider hiring someone to do it. ;)

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette what would be the best way to show a modal IF the user enters incorrect data then?

Comment: Using JavaScript or jQuery... (Not PHP), there is a couple validation plugins... Like [jQuery Validate()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Comment: You want to display the modal after submitting the form based on some conditions in processing the form on the server. So, that would mean you want to display the modal as soon as the page is returned from the server.

Comment: Try the PRG method, I made a tutorial on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14639235/opening-a-modal-window-using-php/44949450#44949450 the modal container is not with bootstrap but you can easily change it

Answer (score 1):

I think that for this purpose it's not very important whether validation is done client side or not. You can change it to client side validation if you wish, but the script you are adding isn't working because it's running before the necessary html elements are loaded. To ensure it runs after, change that line to

```
if ($error) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        });
    </script>
    <?php
} else {
...
```

The script is added only when there is an error, so it will run when loaded but only when the page is reloaded after submission and errors were found.

Comment: I have tried this as well, and I tried it again.  I have given up as I dont have time to figure out how to rewrite it all in javascript.  But just to clarify: This won't work because even if errors were found and the script runs, the document is then reloaded and the modal taken down again anyway? So I would need to have the modal show AFTER the page reloads from the submit being pressed?

Comment: No. What happens is, as the html loads, the javascript it encounters is run unless it's in a function, then it runs when the function is called. Just imagine you are a browser and reading your output line by line. At the time the script is loaded you don't yet know about the html that is below because it is yet to load. So the script runs but has nothing to work on. It finds nothing and therefore does nothing. Putting it inside the `ready` or `load` handler means the script will run only after the full document has been read and loaded.

Comment: @d_peach18 But if this is still not working there may be errors elsewhere in the page. I'll have another look.

Comment: btw have you included the necessary js libraries and css?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and solved it:
You had to `echo` the script because when you end the php code `?>` and start it again `<?php` the code between the end and start will be ignored or always visable/enable. See the exemple below i think that will work!

```
 if ($error) { ?>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $('#myModal').modal('show'); </script>
    <?php
 }
```

Has to be

```
 if ($error) { 
   echo '<script type="text/javascript"> $("#myModal").modal("show")</script>';
 }
```

The `'` in the script are replaced with `"` because a `'` will ignore `"` so it just echo it

Some other things in your code: At the `if ($error)` or `if (!$_Post[...])` It wont work because there is no requirement like `$error = 1` or `T$_Post[...] > "1"` in this case the if will never run
and here :

```
    if (mail("dprb17@gmail.com", "RSVP", "

    Name: ".$_POST['name']."

    Head Count: ".$_POST['head-count']."

    Reception Check: ".$_POST['reception-check']."

    Comments: ".$_POST['comments'])) {
      header("location: http://www.ourpeachwedding.com/pages/thankyou.php");
      exit();
```

There is no consequence

I think when this work it will be very nice!
I hope this will work! Good Luck.... and check your code.